# applying laravel coupon only once for each user

Tags: php, laravel, cart, coupon

I have cart system and everything works just fine, **the only issue that i have is; that each user can use same coupon code over and over**.

> What I want is to **limit each user to be able to use each coupon only
>   once**, and **if user have more than one coupon code only be able to use
>   one of them**.

## Codes

this is my cart update function where my cart will be update with coupon codes etc.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      // quantity
      $qty = $request->input('quantity');
      $products = Product::findOrFail($request->proId);
      $stock = $products->stock;
      $mytime = Carbon::now();
      $couponcode = $request->input('coupon');

      $catId = Coupon::where('category_id', $products->category_id)
                    ->where('value_to', '>=', $mytime)
                    ->when($couponcode, function ($query) use ($couponcode) {
                          return $query->where('title', $couponcode);
                      })
                      ->first();

      if (!empty($qty) && !empty($couponcode)) { // 1. if both (quantity and couponcode) are given
          if ($qty < $stock && (!is_null($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode)) { // if quantity < stock AND coupon-code is correct

              $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                  'name' => $catId->title,
                  'type' => 'coupon',
                  'target' => 'item',
                  'value' => -$catId->amount,
              ));

              Cart::update($id, array(
                  'quantity' => array(
                      'relative' => false,
                      'value' => $qty,
                  ),
              ));
              Cart::addItemCondition($id, $coupon);

              Session::flash('success', 'Cart updated.');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');

          } elseif ($qty > $stock) {
              Session::flash('danger', 'quantity not available!');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');
          } else {
              Session::flash('danger', 'invalid coupon code!');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');
          }
      } elseif (!empty($qty)) { // 2. if just quantity is given   
          if ($qty < $stock) {

              Cart::update($id, array(
                  'quantity' => array(
                      'relative' => false,
                      'value' => $qty,
                  ),
              ));

              Session::flash('success', 'Cart updated.');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');

          } else {
              Session::flash('danger', 'quantity not available!');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');
          }
      } elseif (!empty($couponcode)) { // 3. if just couponcode is given
          if (!is_null($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode) {

              $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                  'name' => $catId->title,
                  'type' => 'coupon',
                  'target' => 'item',
                  'value' => -$catId->amount,
              ));

              Cart::addItemCondition($id, $coupon);

              Session::flash('success', 'Coupon applied successfully.');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');

          } else {
              Session::flash('danger', 'invalid coupon code!');
              return redirect()->route('cart.index');
          }
      } else{ // 1. if nothing is given
            Session::flash('danger', 'Your request cannot be handle, please try again!');
            return redirect()->route('cart.index');
        }
    }
```

## Update

I came up with this query in order to get my cart items conditions name

```
$cartItems = Cart::getContent();
      foreach($cartItems as $item)
      {
          if(is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
            $temp = [];
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $temp[]=[
                    'name' => $value->getName(),
                ];

            }
            $item['_conditions'] = $temp;
            foreach($item['_conditions'] as $itessm)
            {
              $copname[] = $itessm['name'];
            }
          }
      }
```

now `$copname` is conditions names which are stored in my cart session, I need to change my function (above) in order to compare input coupon and see if is exist in my conditions or not, if not let user add it, but is already exist return error.

something like:

`if( $couponcode == $copname )`

any idea?

## UPDATE 2

I changed my code to:

```
$cartItems = Cart::getContent();
      foreach($cartItems as $item)
      {
          if(is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
            $temp = [];
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $key )
            {
                $temp[] = $key['name'];
            }
          }
      }
```

And I get results like:

if no condition exist: `[]`

if conditions exist: `array 2: 0 => 'xxxx', and so on`

then I changed my update function like:

```
    $cartItems = Cart::getContent();
          foreach($cartItems as $item)
          {
              if(is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
                $temp = [];
                foreach($item['conditions'] as $key )
                {
                    // $temp[] = $key['name'];
                    $temp[] = $key['name'];

                }
                $item['_conditions'] = $temp;
              }
          }

//this IF has added
          if($couponcode == $item['_conditions']){
            Session::flash('danger', 'You already used this coupon, you cannot use it again!');
            return redirect()->route('cart.index');
          }else{
            $catId = Coupon::where('category_id', $products->category_id)
                              ->where('value_to', '>=', $mytime)
                              ->when($couponcode, function ($query) use ($couponcode) {
                                    return $query->where('title', $couponcode);
                                })
                                ->first();
          }
```

now the problem here is that i get this error:

> Cannot use object of type Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition as array

anyone?

Comment: did you get solution ?

Comment: not yet.........

Comment: @SagarGautam any idea?

Comment: I've read your question but i've no idea about how laravel cart works :D

Answer (score 0):

You should make it so users can only use a coupon after they have been logged in.

Once they use the coupon, then simply store it to the database, and associate it w/their user account.

When they get to the coupon entry page, once they enter their coupon details, make a ajax call and check to see if the coupon is valid for them to use.

If the application you are working on is software that is out of the box, I personally would create a table called UsedCoupon and give it a minimum of 2 columns which are UserId and CouponCode. I would store my used codes there.

If the application is being created from scratch, you might be able to get away w/storing the used coupon data in a more denormalized manner.

Comment: ok let me explain more maybe it helps, my cart page is only visible to logged users so if you are not login there is no way that you can use coupon code (issue one solved) 2- I'm usin package for my cart and cart data are storing to sessions, how can i check session data to see if user already used coupon or not? (instead of storing it to db as you suggested)

Comment: So, the coupon data gets in session once the user logs in? OR are you saying you have to do all that coding and put it into session, etc?

Comment: no, here is how it works, if user logged in 1-can add product to cart 2-can edit his/her cart such as adding coupons, changing quantities etc. so basically shopping process working only if you are logged in.

Comment: everything is ready and working all i need now is to prevent user of using coupon codes more than once. is like i just need some sort of limit condition in my function that's all.

Comment: ok. so the coupon info is already in session. then you have to retrieve it from the session AND compare it to the coupon that they are trying to use.

so....thats it. do you know how to get data from the session?

Comment: exactly, no i don't know how to get data from the session.

Comment: well? are you there?

Comment: here is how you retrieve data from session: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session
from the docs:

class UserController extends Controller
{
 
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $value = $request->session()->get('key');

        //
    }
}

Comment: and then? first of all what key do i get? how i say exactly what i want? (in my case coupon code) second how compare it in my function??

Comment: not sure what key to get, since i dont know anything about your application. i have no idea how its put together. if this part is already coded, then you should know the key, you can see all the keys in the session variable by doing this: $data = $request->session()->all();

Comment: if i use `$sessions = $request->session()->all();  dd($sessions);` i will get https://ibb.co/nuhS3S

Comment: seems to be nothing in there related to a coupon code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166697/discussion-between-lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs-and-mafortis).